# wxPython - properly close another script

Tags: python, memory-management, wxpython

I have written a wx GUI which calls another script.  I import my script and bind a button to a function that calls main() in the imported script.  Everything is working wonderfully.

I am not closing my accessed script properly though.  I know this because the script manipulates numpy arrays and with each run of the GUI my memory footprint increases by the size of the array.  Obviously, running from the command line this is not an issue as the interpreter exits and the memory is cleared.

What is the proper way (canonical) to go about clearing a previous run of my script from memory without restarting the GUI.  Should I be doing this in the GUI or in the script which is called?

```
from myscript import *

....

#Submit / Cancel
    submit_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Submit")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda e:self.ParseArgs(e, self.args),submit_button)
    self.sizer.Add(submit_button, pos=(10,0), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

....

def ParseArgs(self, e, arg):
    inputarg = []
    inputarg.append(arg['input'])
    pystretch.main(arg, inputarg)
```

Comment: You can use multithreading, where you start a thread then create a timer, and when the timer disconnects the thread restarts.

Comment: Are you keeping a handle on the procedure you're calling? If so, you'll need to delete that. Otherwise, create a small runnable example that we can play with.